# Custom error handling is catching errors that normally are not displayed

Tags: perl, file, error-handling, stat

I am having a problem I can't seem to figure out and I hope you guys can help me.
The problem occurs when :

- I use custom errorhandling
- I use File::Stat in a seperate module

Example:

Main file

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# signal handling
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my $error = @_;
    chomp $error;
    print "die: $error\n";
};

require mod; 

mod->get_stat();
```

Module

```
package mod;

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;

sub get_stat {
    my $file_path = "test.txt";
    my $file_size = stat($file_path)->size;
    print $file_size;
}

1;
```

This will cause the following output:

```
die: 1
die: 1
die: 1
die: 1
die: 1
4
```

Now, if I remove my custom error handling OR if I **use** mod instead of **require** the die's will not be displayed.

Interesting to see is that it **does** actually produce a result (test.txt is 4 bytes), meaning **stat** is working as it should.

So, why am I getting this error ? Is this really an error ? Does the default perl error handling ignore errors that are "1"?

**EDIT**
As Linus Kleen remarked, the reason I get "1" is because I am displaying the amount of elements in the array.

If I print out the content of the error instead, I get the following error:

```
die: Your vendor has not defined Fcntl macro S_ISVTX, used at c:/Perl64/lib/File/stat.pm line 37.

die: Your vendor has not defined Fcntl macro S_IFSOCK, used at c:/Perl64/lib/File/stat.pm line 41.

die: Your vendor has not defined Fcntl macro S_IFBLK, used at c:/Perl64/lib/File/stat.pm line 41.

die: S_IFFIFO is not a valid Fcntl macro at c:/Perl64/lib/File/stat.pm line 41.

die: Your vendor has not defined Fcntl macro S_IFLNK, used at c:/Perl64/lib/File/stat.pm line 41.

4
```

But still, I am getting an error that, without custom error handling, I do not get.

Comment: require will return last executable statement form your package

Comment: Ahhh... So it's Perl running in Windows? Which one is it?

Comment: Windows 7 with ActivePerl 5.12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG), due to an implementation glitch `$SIG{__DIE__}` hooks get called even when code [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)s inside an [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).  When [File::stat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::stat) is loaded, it checks to see what constants [Fcntl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Fcntl) supports on your platform.  It catches the errors caused by unsupported constants, but not before your hook sees them.

You can tell if you're in an `eval` by checking the value of [`$^S`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT).  If it's not 0, then you're in an eval.

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    return unless defined $^S and $^S == 0; # Ignore errors in eval
    my ($error) = @_;
    chomp $error;
    print "die: $error\n";
};
```

You don't see the errors when you `use` instead of `require` because `use` is a compile-time operation and `require` is a run-time operation (as is setting `%SIG`).  When you `use mod` and it `use`s File::stat, that all happens *before* you set up your hook.  When you `require mod`, that doesn't happen until *after* you've installed your hook.

Answer (score 6):

Change it to

```
my ($error) = @_;
```

You're using scalar context in your code example which will give you the number of elements in `@_`, which is one.

Comment: Correct, thanks, but still I am getting an error that, without custom error handling, I do not get.